# Creating a ceylon.test.TestRunner

Tags: unit-testing, ceylon

I'm trying to create a test suite that I can run programmatically. ([The documentation](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/test/1.3.3.1/module-doc/api/index.html) does [mention](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/test/1.3.3.1/module-doc/api/index.html#running) that one can tease an IDE into doing the test running, but it seems to me a more regular approach to set up the test suite as a standard Ceylon module that has its own [runnable unit](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/ide/intellij/getting-started/). Also, the documentation doesn't say anything about how to actually do it the IDE way).

So, I'm creating a [TestRunner](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/test/1.3.3.1/module-doc/api/TestRunner.type.html) using the [createTestRunner](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/test/1.3.3.1/module-doc/api/index.html#createTestRunner) function. Said function takes a Sequential of [TestSource](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/test/1.3.3.1/module-doc/api/index.html#TestSource)s ('`TestSource[]`') as its first argument. `TestSource` is an alias for this type:

```
Module|Package|ClassDeclaration|FunctionDeclaration|Class<Anything,Nothing>|FunctionModel<Anything,Nothing>|String
```

Which promts the question: *How do I want to feed my tests to the test runner?*

For starters it seems easiest to put them in local functions and then let the test runner access these functions somehow (not further specified).
As the long list of types that are included in the `TestSource` alias doesn't seem to include actual [Functions](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/language/1.3.3/module-doc/api/meta/model/Function.type.html), I tried to go for the nearest candidate that looked like the right thing: [FunctionDeclaration](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/ast/core/1.3.2/module-doc/api/FunctionDeclaration.type.html).

In order to make such a function declaration, I first had to ponder how my test wrapper functions might actually look like. Perhaps something like this?

```
Anything myTests1 () {
    // assert something!
    return null;
}

void myTests2 () {
    // assert some more things!
}
```

([these functions are typewise equivalent](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/tour/functions/), by the way)

After a lot of [Ceylon Herd scrutiny](https://modules.ceylon-lang.org/repo/1/ceylon/ast/core/1.3.2/module-doc/api/index.html), I figured that a `FunctionDeclaration` for such functions could be spelled out like this:

```
// function name for function declaration:
LIdentifier funName = LIdentifier("myName");

// type of return value for function declaration:
UIdentifier returnTypeName1 = UIdentifier("Anything");
TypeNameWithTypeArguments returnTypeName2 = TypeNameWithTypeArguments(returnTypeName1);
BaseType returnType = BaseType( returnTypeName2 );

// type of parameters for function declaration:
Sequential<Parameter> parameters1 = [];  // our test wrapper functions takes no arguments
Parameters parameters2 = Parameters( parameters1 );
Sequence<Parameters> parameterLists = [parameters2];

// the actual function declaration:
FunctionDeclaration myFunctionDeclaration = FunctionDeclaration(
    funName,
    returnType,
    parameterLists
);
```

So now, all I had to do was to feed this to the `createTestRunner` function. I just had to put `myFunctionDeclaration` into a `TestSource[]`:

```
TestSource myTestSource = myFunctionDeclaration;
TestSource[] mySourceList = [myTestSource];
TestRunner myTestRunner = createTestRunner(mySourceList);
```

But that first line doesn't work. `myFunctionDeclaration` of type 'FunctionDeclaration' simply doesn't pass as a `TestSource` type. Why not? Is `FunctionDeclaration` not a proper TestSource type? Looking at the alias definition for `TestSource`, `FunctionDeclaration` seems to be *right there* in the list of possible types:

```
Module|Package|ClassDeclaration|FunctionDeclaration|Class<Anything,Nothing>|FunctionModel<Anything,Nothing>|String
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `FunctionDeclaration` literal:

```
`function myTests1`
```

(As opposed to a `Function`, which is `` `myTests1` `` without the keyword. The first is a *detyped* model in `ceylon.language.meta.declaration`, the second a statically typed model in `ceylon.language.meta.model`. See [Tour, The metamodel](https://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.3/tour/annotations/#the_metamodel).)

So I think what you’re supposed to do for test runners is:

```
value myTestRunner = createTestRunner([`function myTests1`, `function myTests2`]);
```

(But I’ve never done that myself.)

What you found on Herd is `ceylon.ast`, a completely unrelated set of modules that lets you describe *Ceylon source code*. Your `myFunctionDeclaration` describes the Abstract Syntax Tree of the function

```
Anything myName();
```

but only at the syntax level: the function is never compiled. You don’t need `ceylon.ast` for metamodel stuff. (Note also that this is a function *declaration*, not a function *definition*. It’s syntactically valid, but won’t be accepted by the typechecker because it’s not annotated `formal`.)

As a side note, the `ceylon.ast.create` module offers much more convenient ways to instantiate `ceylon.ast.core` nodes (instead of using that module directly, as you did):

```
value fun = functionDefinition {
    name = "myName";
    type = baseType("Anything");
};
```

Comment: I get `Error:(50, 49) ceylon: metamodel reference to local declaration`. If I then take away my two function declarations (`mytTests1` and `myTests2`) I get `Error:(50, 49) ceylon: function or value is not defined: 'myTests1'`

Comment: Are `myTests1` and `myTests2` functions defined inside another function? You can’t take metamodel references of such declarations (“local declarations” in the error message), you’ll have to make them toplevel functions, or class methods, or something similar. (Keep in mind that in the Web IDE, there’s an implicit `run` function around all your code. Check the “advanced” checkbox to change that.)

Comment: Moved them to top level, and, it compiles! :D